# What gauge size and fuse should I use?

Tags: wiring, 12v, fuses

I've purchased a [Thlevel Car USB Charger Socket](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dbTHjofrL._AC_SX679_.jpg) to install in my 12v system campervan and I'm confused regarding the fuse and wire I need to use to wire things together. By my calculations, given that I could be using all the sockets at the same time, I would need around a 30 amp fuse and a 12 gauge wire (4 mm2). But then I wonder, what if I'm using most of the time only the usb chargers (each only 2.1A). Wouldn't it be that the wire and fuse is too big? Could someone point me out in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `most of the time` is not `all of the time`

Comment: I missed these kind of answers from my nerd buddies in the university... To make it clear, this is really not my area. I was hoping to understand this since I read that big wires are not a good option for small needs in terms of amperage and also how big amp fuse can actually be of any protecting use for such small amperage needs (again when only the usb are being used)

Comment: If you could point me out which wire/fuse I should pick, I'd really appreciate

Comment: Doesn't the seller of the thing give good information about what you should use?

Comment: No, that's why I'm asking here :)

Comment: I would determine what you're going to plug in that would draw the most power. Then size the wire based on the max current draw. Otherwise, what's the point in buying something with a bunch of outlets if you're going to only be able to use 1 at a time.

Comment: For USB charging it would be overkill. But someone might plug in a coffee maker and two other high current equipment, and then the wire from battery must be able to carry this current without heating up and starting a fire, or the fuse has to be rated low enough to protect the smaller wire.

Comment: Choose the wire size to be capable of safely handling the maximum current draw you ever expect to see from all outlets combined. Remember that 2.1A @ 5A *out* of a USB adapter is probably only 1A @ 12V *in*. Once you've chosen a wire size, choose an appropriate fuse to protect the wire.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: @Justme That's exactly my case. I want to be able to use the usb sockets plus those kind of appliances together.

Comment: @brhans I understand that I need to choose a wire that is capable of dealing with the total amperage needed, my doubt is about the fuse. Say I'm using a fuse that protects the whole circuit, 20/30 Amps for example. Wouldn't this fuse be too high for the case of protecting the usb sockets? Or should I care only about protecting the wire, in which case it would be covered if I choose an appropriate one? Or should I add an extra fuse only for the usb socket connection? Thanks!

Comment: @PedroB The USB socket has a step-down converter. It most likely never takes in more than 2A of 12V, so if you want, you can put a separate smaller fuse there like 3A or 4A. However, if the USB converter ever breaks, and outputs 12V instead of 5V, the damage is already done, and any 5V equipment will be toast.

Comment: @Justme Thank you!

Comment: As with household wiring, the fuse (or circuit breaker) is there to protect the permanently installed wiring from overheating and causing a fire. The individual devices plugged in are responsible for protecting themselves - and you'll almost certainly find in any 12V to USB adapter that there's a small glass fuse in the adapter (usually you can unscrew the end to find it).

Comment: @brhans Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot answer in the comments I'll add some little tips.

About the wiring, if you don't want to bother with calculation (usually better but some quick answer might be sufficient), there is some web calculator that I found well designed: [circuitcalculator](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2007/09/20/wire-parameter-calculator/).

When you define your wire size, take around 20% margin of your wire max current as a max fuse.

About your fuse issue on USB socket, well since it is integrated you cannot add fuse between the internal DCDC converter (12V -> 5V) to add the right fuse.  (as @Justme said it have big chances to be a step down converter).

Since you are blind on the efficiency of the converter (it could be LDO or high efficiency converter), You can plus a calibrated resistor that leads you to 1A @5V and check the voltage on 12V line. If it is around 0.5A @12V it means that you have >80% efficiency.
So take the max you think it can handle, calculate the approximate current on 12V you get and maybe take a 20% margin on your fuse choice.

Hope that's helpful